# SSIS Datatype issue with different options

Tags: ssis, data-mapping

Does anyone know how do the options 'Copy data from one or more tables or view' and 'Write a query to specify the data to transfer' in Import & Export Wizard function differently?

During testing, I tried using both options to transfer a table from a source to destination but I am getting different datatypes mapping.

For 'Copy data from one or more tables or view' option, all the datatypes mapping are correct. However, if I use 'Write a query to specify the data to transfer' option, some dataypes would appear as numbers instead of its appropriate datatype. Eg: Under type column, it shows 1 instead of Char.

I think I can rule out Mapping files as the cause because I would be getting the same error for both options if that's the case. What I would like to ask is if anyone knows whether the query is being parsed differently with those options? If so, how is it different?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm no way a SSIS expert but my experience leads me to believe that that Query option executes the query for a limited set of rows and infers the types from that. Whereas the other option will build the transfer based on type metadata in the DB(s).